# sqlite3 operational error when inserting new data

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a database wxpython GUI for my suppliers, within this insert new supplier function I am creating a new supplier contact. I cannot find what is causing this error.  The function is below along with where the error is occurring.

```
def insertNew(self,event):

        with con:
                cur = con.cursor()

                cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Suppliers (Supplier, Code, Commodity, Contact, Number, EmailContact, TechnicalContact, TechnicalContactEmail, Address,) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                            (self.text_list[0].GetValue(), self.text_list[1].GetValue(), self.text_list[2].GetValue(), self.text_list[3].GetValue(), self.text_list[4].GetValue(),
                              self.text_list[5].GetValue(), self.text_list[6].GetValue(), self.text_list[7].GetValue(), self.text_list[8].GetValue()))
                con.commit()
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ONP1LDY\eclipse-workspace\WOrk\SupplierDB.py", line 169, in insertNew
    self.text_list[5].GetValue(), self.text_list[6].GetValue(), self.text_list[7].GetValue(), self.text_list[8].GetValue()))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

Can anyone see where the error is coming from?

Comment: Your indentation on the next line of `self` doesn't match the preceding one

Comment: You have a comma after address that shouldn't be there. Change: 
TechnicalContactEmail, Address, to TechnicalContactEmail, Address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the comma after `Adress`, it's waiting for another column identifier:

```
cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Suppliers (Supplier, Code, Commodity, Contact, Number, EmailContact, TechnicalContact, TechnicalContactEmail, Address) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                            (self.text_list[0].GetValue(), self.text_list[1].GetValue(), self.text_list[2].GetValue(), self.text_list[3].GetValue(), self.text_list[4].GetValue(),
                              self.text_list[5].GetValue(), self.text_list[6].GetValue(), self.text_list[7].GetValue(), self.text_list[8].GetValue()))
```